# Android XML: "conflicts with another tag that has the same ID"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I recently deleted a fragment including its layout and viewmodel from my project. (FragmentAddFlight, VmAddFlight, fragment_add_flight.xml)

Surprisingly I am getting these errors:

```
    [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cImageView id\u003d\u0027@+id/imageView2\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":277,"col0":20,"line1":286,"col1":85}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView4\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":308,"col0":28,"line1":312,"col1":64}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/editText8\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":314,"col0":28,"line1":318,"col1":60}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView5\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":327,"col0":28,"line1":331,"col1":63}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView14\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":333,"col0":28,"line1":338,"col1":57}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cImageView id\u003d\u0027@+id/imageView2\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":369,"col0":20,"line1":378,"col1":72}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView4\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":400,"col0":28,"line1":404,"col1":60}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/editText8\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":406,"col0":28,"line1":410,"col1":60}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView5\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":419,"col0":28,"line1":423,"col1":71}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView14\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":425,"col0":28,"line1":430,"col1":57}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cImageView id\u003d\u0027@+id/imageView2\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":452,"col0":20,"line1":461,"col1":77}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView4\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":483,"col0":28,"line1":487,"col1":60}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/editText8\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":489,"col0":28,"line1":493,"col1":60}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView5\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":502,"col0":28,"line1":506,"col1":71}]}
  [databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView14\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Documents\\Android-Projekte\\FlightLogger\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_add_flight.xml","pos":[{"line0":508,"col0":28,"line1":513,"col1":57}]}
```

Remember the file referenced in these error has already been deleted. Why do I get these errors?

I cleaned the project via Build -> clean project. I tried to rebuild the project via the same menu. But the result remains the same.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

These files are created at compile time, so they might not have been deleted, Try invalidate caches and restart in android studio.

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 6):

If you use view-binding, you can add this to the layout till you have better IDs for the Views:

```
tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
```

Do it for each problematic layout.

I found this tip from [here](https://proandroiddev.com/new-in-android-viewbindings-the-difference-from-databinding-library-bef5945baf5e).

Answer (score 4):

`Invalidate Caches/Restart` option sometime not working.

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

Just try this command then see issue will no more available.

Answer (score 3):

To add on how to invalidate caches, in Android Studio, go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 3):

if `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart` cannot solve your problem. Maybe you can try to

1. delete

```
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding =  true
    }
```

2. Invalidate
3. Close AndroidStudio
4. if your system is `Windows`, open `resource monitor`(because my computer is Chinese, so I don't know how to translate this word in the English system. Open `cmd`, input `perfmon`, and you will see it.)
5. Click the `CPU`->`Associated handle`->Search `android`.
6. Close all the associated  handle,then open your AndroidStudio and add the

```
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding =  true
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes none of the tricks explained above works as expected. Invalidate Cache and Restart Android Studio did not work for me at all. I tried the following command as well

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

But it only works one time. I have to do this every time I make changes to the layout file. Try following these tricks if none of it is working for you

- **Rename the layout file**. You might want to change the Binding class as well
- Export the Project and as zip, unzip it in a different locations and open the existing project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was the same ID assigned to different views in my XML file.
I just changed one of them to avoid conflict then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Compile Time Issues:
Fixed:
1.Clean the project.
2.clear cache and restart.

Make sure View binding is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you accidentally make a layout-26 folder and inside that, there are two XML files of the same name.

Solution-:

1.Move the correct XML file from the layout-26 folder to the layout folder

2.Delete the layout-26 folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting such issue then follow these instructions

if your system is Windows,

1. Open cmd, input perfmon, and you will see there.
2. "open resource monitor" just click on this option
3. Click the CPU->Associated handle->Search android.
4. Close all the associated handle,then open your AndroidStudio

Now you get there is no such error.
This process is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't make it go without killing existing Gradle processes.

on Linux terminal:

```bash
pkill -f '.*GradleDaemon.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this problem arise when you refactor(Rename) id in current file and it change that id in full project and this problem arises..

Answer (score 0):

Any declaration of an id in an xml-layout should be unique.

This will be global in your app:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLayoutId"
```

whilst this will not be global

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/myLayoutId"
```

It won't be a problem usually, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score -1):

None of the above works for me: `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true" , invalidate caches, gradlew assembleDebug`. All is not works.

The only way I found is **delete the whole project and pull the source code again from git**. Then build -> it run normally