# databinding … conflicts with an ID used by a view in this layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm having a trouble using the <include> element in my layout files. The exact error is:

```
[databinding] {"msg":"\u003cinclude id\u003d\u0027@+id/displayArea\u0027\u003e conflicts with an ID used by a view in this layout","file":"badlayout/res/layout-land/main.xml","pos":[{"line0":10,"col0":2,"line1":20,"col1":16}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"\u003cinclude id\u003d\u0027@+id/displayArea\u0027\u003e conflicts with an ID used by a view in this layout","file":"badlayout/res/layout-port/main.xml","pos":[{"line0":10,"col0":2,"line1":10,"col1":67}]}
```

The problem happens when I set `android:id` in an <include> element in layout-port/main.xml:

```
<include android:id="@+id/displayArea" layout="@layout/display" />
```

while using the same ID directly in layout-land/main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/displayArea"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Experimenting shows I can't mix-n-match these. I can either specify `android:id` in the <include> tags, or in ordinary views, but not both.

Can anybody explain exactly what this message means, and what the rules are?

This is all complicated by the fact that you also can't set `android:id` at the top level of a layout file without running into different problems.

This is an older app. These layout files never gave me any trouble in Eclipse; I only started getting the errors after moving to Android Studio.

---

For completeness, the complete xml files are shown here:

**layout-land/main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/displayArea"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:baselineAligned="false">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-port/main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <include android:id="@+id/displayArea" layout="@layout/display" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/display.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/StatusLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you use a different id for the include layout? I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the same id. If you have to use the same id, try removing the "+" from the id for the include file. If that doesn't work, which version of data binding, etc are you using?

Comment: The java code is calling `displayArea = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.displayArea);`. I suppose I *could* use a different name for included layouts, and then have the java code try one name then the other. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not a great solution. Have you tried invalidating caches and restarting? I see where others have had the same issue and that has been the solution.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841211/ and other results from googling the error message. No joy there, it's genuinely an issue with how `android:id` is processed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: invalidate and restart]

1. invalidate and restart
2. **And remember Restart Mac**

Furthermore, You have to make sure there isn't same ID.